# Eliminate middle lines using sed

Tags: sed

I have the following log format

```
2017-12-22T23:32:07-05:00 ServerABC sshd[22549]: Accepted password for JohnBlezard from 192.168.1.1 port 81111 ssh2
2017-12-22T23:32:07-05:00 ServerABC sshd[60944]: Accepted password for JohnBlezard from 192.168.1.1 port 81111 ssh2
2017-12-22T23:32:07-05:00 ServerABC sshd[1787]: [ID 800047 dns.info] Accepted password for JohnBlezard from 192.168.1.1 port 81111 ssh2
2017-12-22T23:32:13-05:00 ServerABC sshd[1367]: [ID 800047 dns.info] Accepted password for JohnBlezard from 192.168.1.1 port 81111 ssh2
2017-12-22T23:32:14-05:00 ServerABC sshd[36061]: Accepted password for JohnBlezard from 192.168.1.1 port 81111 ssh2
2017-12-22T23:32:17+00:00 ServerABC sshd[31616]: Accepted password for JohnBlezard from 192.168.1.1 port 81111 ssh2
```

I have been using the command below to parse it out. However I can't seem to get rid of the "[ID: 800047 dns.info]"

Is there an easier way to use sed to eliminate the middle line?

```
grep -E '(Accepted|for JohnBlezard)' testing.txt | grep "JohnBlezard from" | awk '{print $2, $5, $7, $9, $11}'
```

The expected result should be as follows

```
[ServerABC] [password] [JohnBlezard] [IP Address]
```

But after parsing out, I am noticing in some lines it is coming out as

```
[ServerABC] [ID 800047] [Accepted] [for] [from]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove those lines with `grep -v`

From `man grep`

```
       -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)
```

So

```
$ cat test
2017-12-22T23:32:07-05:00 ServerABC sshd[22549]: Accepted password for JohnBlezard from 192.168.1.1 port 81111 ssh2
2017-12-22T23:32:07-05:00 ServerABC sshd[60944]: Accepted password for JohnBlezard from 192.168.1.1 port 81111 ssh2
2017-12-22T23:32:07-05:00 ServerABC sshd[1787]: [ID 800047 dns.info] Accepted password for JohnBlezard from 192.168.1.1 port 81111 ssh2
2017-12-22T23:32:13-05:00 ServerABC sshd[1367]: [ID 800047 dns.info] Accepted password for JohnBlezard from 192.168.1.1 port 81111 ssh2
2017-12-22T23:32:14-05:00 ServerABC sshd[36061]: Accepted password for JohnBlezard from 192.168.1.1 port 81111 ssh2
2017-12-22T23:32:17+00:00 ServerABC sshd[31616]: Accepted password for JohnBlezard from 192.168.1.1 port 81111 ssh2
```

Expected result

```
$ grep -E '(Accepted|for JohnBlezard)' test | grep -v "\[ID" | grep "JohnBlezard from" | awk '{print $2, $5, $7, $9, $11}'
ServerABC password JohnBlezard 192.168.1.1 81111
ServerABC password JohnBlezard 192.168.1.1 81111
ServerABC password JohnBlezard 192.168.1.1 81111
ServerABC password JohnBlezard 192.168.1.1 81111
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it was so easy.

Comment: @JohnBlezard No problem! Please, if you found either this or RomanPerekhrest's answers as a great solution, feel free to mark anyone as the solution so others with the same situation, can find the solution faster.

Answer (score 1):

With single **`awk`** command:

```
awk '/Accepted .+ for JohnBlezard/{ 
         if ($4 == "[ID") { $5 = $8; $7 = $10; $9 = $12; $11 = $14 }
         print $2, $5, $7, $9, $11
     }' test.txt
```

The output:

```
ServerABC password JohnBlezard 192.168.1.1 81111
ServerABC password JohnBlezard 192.168.1.1 81111
ServerABC password JohnBlezard 192.168.1.1 81111
ServerABC password JohnBlezard 192.168.1.1 81111
ServerABC password JohnBlezard 192.168.1.1 81111
ServerABC password JohnBlezard 192.168.1.1 81111
```

Comment: Apologies for asking silly question but should I be typing all this in one line?

Comment: @JohnBlezard, it may go either in one line or in multiple lines. As long as readability does matter

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it and it worked great as well.

Comment: @JohnBlezard, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this sed

```
sed -E '
 h
  s/(.*: (\[[^\]*\] )*)//
  s/(( *[^ ]*){6})(.*)/\1/
  s/( *[^ ]* )([^ ]*)/[\2] /g
 x
  s/([^ ]* )([^ ]*).*/ [\2]/
 G
  y/\n/ /
' infile
```